# How to write a function to combine folder path and file name?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to pass the full path of a text file to one of the function.
i am placing the my script, and text file at same location
by using the below command i found the folder path where my script is

```
p = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

`p` came as `C:\test`

my file name is `xyz.txt`

i want to pass the the argument to the function as `C:\test\xyz.txt`

how can i combine path and file name

i tried below code

```
path =  p & "xyz.txt"
```

can any one help me how can join the path and file name.

Comment: sorry path = & p & "xyz.txt"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You *can* use string concatenation to build a path. The correct way to do it, however, is to use the FileSystemObject's [`BuildPath()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt(v=vs.84).aspx), because this will do the right thing with the backslashes under all circumstances.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

scriptPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
textFilePath = FSO.BuildPath(scriptPath, "xyz.txt")

MsgBox textFilePath
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this code :

```
Option Explicit
Msgbox GetFilePath("xyz.txt")
'******************************************************
Function GetFilePath(FileName)
Dim fso,scriptPath
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
scriptPath = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
GetFilePath = FSO.BuildPath(scriptPath,FileName)
End Function
'******************************************************
```

Comment: This is a bit problematic because it leaves the false impression that it magically can find the full path of a file, while all it really does is prepend the current directory. `GetAbsolutePathName()` is meant to sanitize an unclean (or relative) path, not to retrieve the path of a file. Also, it's not necessarily true the the current directory of the process is the one the VBScript file is in.

Comment: @Tomalak i edit my answer with your remark into function ! Thank you !